# calling pcolor results in error with shading

Tags: python, matplotlib

While trying to use `matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor` to make a 2D plot on one of the axes (as shown below), I get an error.

```py
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, len(cs_values)+1, figsize=(11,4), dpi=200)
im0 = ax[0].pcolor(X, Y, Q[:-1, :-1], shading='auto')
```

The error I am getting is:

```py
/path/to/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 970, in _update_property
.format(type(self).__name__, k))
 AttributeError: 'PolyCollection' object has no property 'shading'
```

I am using Matplotlib 3.1.3 on Python 3.7. What is causing the error and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error, though I am running newer versions of Matplotlib (3.7.1) and Python (3.10.11). `pcolormesh` is recommended over `pcolor`. Do you get the same error there? (`pcolormesh` is a drop-in replacement.)

Comment: @jared yes I get the same error with it

Comment: I created a new environment with Python 3.7.16 and Matplolib 3.1.3 and I got the same error using `pcolor`, but I did not get the error using `pcolormesh`. Looking at the documentation for Matplotlib 3.1.3, this seems consistent because [`pcolor`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor.html) does not have a `shading` argument while [`pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html) does (in 3.7.1, `pcolor` has the `shading` argument). Are you sure you get the same error with `pcolormesh`?